# Sending email(gmail) from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I want to send a email when the user does a specific interaction in gmail. And I am going to develop a chrome extension for this purpose. I can inject a content script into gmail to achieve this.

But regarding email sending part, I can open a compose window with the message pre-filled. And the user has to send it manually. But is it possible to send the mail without interrupting the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you think that users will not like this ? They don't want to be a mail sender without knowing that.

The best solution is to :

1. Ask user permission to authorize [Gmail OAuth API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview)
2. Send Ajax request to your server with email parameters (to, subject, body, etc.)
3. Send mail through SMTP with Gmail OAuth API
4. Display a [notification](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/) for sending success

Comment: Good answer. However, if this is a Chrome extension for GMail, it *would* be ok to send an email on behalf of user. In which case it is best to emulate "Send" button click so that user sees the same UI interaction as if he clicked it himself.